# How come I can invoke a function declared below a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I thought functions in Javascript couldn't be invoked if defined below where they're invoked (unless hoisting is involved).

However, in React the code below will output "Hello beta". How come?

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {alpha()}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const alpha = () => beta();

const beta = () => "beta";
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-kalam-idw8y?file=/src/App.js:0-203

Comment: It is possible as long as the invocation does not occur before the definition. Maybe related to the concept of the topic of "temporary dead zone". Hoisting is involved, but limited to the variable declaration; the assigned value (function) is not hoisted.

Comment: This is a good question

Comment: That's the beauty of JS 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alpha` isn't invoked until `App` is, and that doesn't happen until the entire file has been parsed.

Defining a function does not invoke it.

Comment: But how is beta being called when it is created after invoking it ? Shouldn't that give an error

Comment: @ThanveerShah — As I said in this answer, it is created **before** it is invoked.